# multiple SLF4J bindings with m2e in Eclipse 2020-06

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Got a problem getting *slf4j* working for me with *m2e*.
This is not the first time to state this problem. However, others have a more specific case and still no answer.

I installed Eclipse-jee fresh. For test I created a simplest maven project from *maven-archetype-quickstart*. It simply prints out *Hello World!*

Although applying *m2e* it compiles and runs fine, I get the messages in red

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/rschumacher/install/eclipse-jee/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/rschumacher/install/eclipse-jee/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

This happens with any maven project when performing *run as/Maven test*.
It doesn't help to look at the *dependency:tree* of the *pom.xml*, as the conflicting bindings are with **m2e and osgi** (as far as I can interprete the messages).

As result, **slf4j** ignores the configuration and **is no longer usable** from within Eclipse with *m2e* installed.
If I start *mvn test* from a commandline, no such messages appear. *slf4j* logging is working as it should.

Do you got any idea or workaround in order to have *slf4j* working again with *m2e*?

Comment: Have you considered opening a bug report on m2e?

Comment: Now I found it is already reported: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506676
and unsolved since 2016. This means to me: If you want to use slf4j in a maven project, forget about Eclipse as long as the bug is open - as I do not know about a workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Latest Update:

Pls see [JMR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64179705/11457476)'s answer for More comprehensive solution

---

You should go to Window -> preference -> Maven -> Installations

Then instead of using EMBEDDED m2e, add an external one, which you has installed manually, then choose it and apply.

[eclipse preference screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yt7s.png)

This how I resolve this problem.
So according to same mechanism, you may resolve this problem also by delete maven in system path.

Comment: This didn't resolve it for me, and I have the exact same error as the OP.

Answer (score 11):

With the help of Nickel Cao's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63879608/12849117), I was (eventually) able to fix the SLF4J error/warning messages you are describing. However, Nickel's solution only fixed the default Maven Run As goals. My custom Maven build goals - the only goals I ever use - also had to be updated before the SLF4J errors went away.

**NOTE:** I fixed the problem in Eclipse 2020-09, not 2020-06.

Here's how I did it, with some screenshots. (Sorry, I don't have the reputation to embed them.)

1. Add your external Maven installation directory in Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations:
   [Screenshot of Maven Installations dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfSSb.png)
   (I'm pretty sure the checkbox is how you select the default Maven runtime..)
2. Open the Run Configurations dialog by clicking Run As -> Run Configurations from the Project's context menu:
   [Screenshot of Project's Run As context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT9Ql.png)
3. Update each of your custom Maven build configurations to use the external Maven Runtime:
   [Screenshot of Run Configurations dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7yJ6.png)

Once I had performed this last step, my custom Run-As Maven builds stopped generating the SLF4J errors:
[Screenshot of victory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUJZv.png)

Cheers!

Comment: Works for me in Eclipse 2021-03. Apparently the global preference does not get applied to the run configurations.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne I believe the default preference is applied to new Run configurations, but existing configs do not get updated. That's what Steps 2&3 are for - pointing your existing Run configs at the external Maven installation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have should be fixed for the EMBEDDED Maven runtime since Eclipse m2e 1.18.2.
Eclipse m2e 1.19.0, which also includes the fix, is part of the Eclipse 2021-12 release.

If you are interested, this is the PullRequest in the m2e GitHub repository that fixed the issue:
https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/pull/369